# Necesito un código en sql para Juntar dos tablas con datos en común y agregar un campo adicional

Tags: sql

```
[BDODSIS_019_2018_01].[dbo]
[I_Atencion]
ate_Idnum    ate_UE   ate_dni  ate_idsexo  ate_fecatencion
552756440     1224   46604842      0         02/01/2018
552756503     1224   47005620      0         01/01/2018
552756510     1224   40818200      0         02/01/2018
552756517     1224   73942824      0         02/01/2018
552756523     1224   80923726      0         02/01/2018

[FuasNoSuperanRC_201803_F_1].[dbo].
[Hoja1]
DISA     RC    SERVICIO AFI# LOTE  AFI# NUMERO  AFI# SEXO
JUNIN   017      056       2         46604742      0
JUNIN   042      056       2         46604842      0
JUNIN   042      904       2         47005620      0
JUNIN   017      018       2         73941824      0
JUNIN   042      018       2         73942824      0
```

Necesito: (ate_dni=AFI# NUMERO)

```
ate_Idnum    ate_UE   ate_dni  ate_idsexo  ate_fecatencion  SERVICIO
552756440     1224   46604842      0          02/01/2018       056
552756503     1224   47005620      0          01/01/2018       904
552756517     1224   73942824      0          02/01/2018       018
```

Comment: Hola Leono ,bienvenido a SO.Necesitamos que añadas a la pregunta el codigo que has intentado hasta el momento para poder ayudarte mejor,te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido de bienvenida https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que aprendas a como hacer correctamente una pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro sobre los nombres de columnas que estás usando (¿se pueden usar '#' en nombres de columnas sin que cause problemas a los select?)

Pero tu query debería ser algo así:

```
Select a.ate_Idnum, a.ate_UE,a.ate_dni, a.ate_idsexo, a.ate_fecatencion, b.SERVICIO 
from [BDODSIS_019_2018_01].[dbo].[I_Atencion] a
join [FuasNoSuperanRC_201803_F_1].[dbo].[Hoja1] b
on a.[ate_dni]=b.[AFI# NUMERO]
```

Comment: Hola Killbunny el código que presentas genera el siguiente error:           
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 37
No se puede resolver el conflicto de intercalación entre "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" y "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" de la operación equal to.

Comment: Ese es un error diferente, es porque la codificación es diferente entre las dos tablas, te sugiero que leas sobre la función COLLATE ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms184391(v=sql.120).aspx ) para que puedas convertir ambas tablas a la misma codificación de caracteres